# Place text in front / on top of a Dash Graph object

Tags: python, plotly-python

I need to have a message shown if a condition is met. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637861/how-to-not-show-default-dcc-graph-template-in-dash) that deals with showing a blank graph but couldn't figure out how to apply for my needs.
The graph's function:

```
import plotly.express as px

@app.callback(
Output("graph-figure", "figure"),
Input("dropdown_a", "value"),
Input("dropdown_x", "value"),
Input("dropdown_y", "value"))

def update_graph(a, x_axis, y_axis):
    df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\user\project\Data.csv")
    # in this case a message needs to be shown instead of the graph
    if x_axis == y_axis:
         #  ...
    return px.bar(df, x=x_axis, y=y_axis)
```

The Graph object:

```
html.Div(dcc.Graph(id="graph-figure"))
```

If you think that more information is needed, tell me and I'll provide it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: calling a function that returns new values for the graph's `layout`:

The function (can be modified, of course):

```
def show_message(message):
    return {
        "layout": {
            "xaxis": {"visible": False},
            "yaxis": {"visible": False},
            "annotations": [
                {
                    "text": message,
                    "xref": "paper",
                    "yshift": "90",
                    "showarrow": False,
                    "font": {"size": 20, "color": "gray"},
                }
            ],
        }
    }
```

Calling the function:

```
def update_graph(a, x_axis, y_axis):
    df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\user\project\Data.csv")
    # in this case a message needs to be shown instead of the graph
    if x_axis == y_axis:
         show_message('Message to show')
    return px.bar(df, x=x_axis, y=y_axis)
```