# Plotly Dash: How to change image on button click

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I had unknowingly added in the answer section of the following thread as I was trying to use that example to complete my usecase:

[Plotly: How to display graph after clicking a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811550/plotly-how-to-display-graph-after-clicking-a-button/69957171#69957171)

I am looking for a very similar solution and I tried suggestion 2 (from the above thread), because I want to display images depending upon user's choice of clicking button. I have `image_1`, `image_2`, `image_3` and `image_4` under one directory. I have tried so far like below:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px

pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
from datetime import datetime

palette = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Prices': [1, 10, 7, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'Predicted_prices': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, 8, 6, 9]})

# app setup
app = dash.Dash()

# controls
controls = dcc.Card(
    [dcc.FormGroup(
        [
            dcc.Label("Options"),
            dcc.RadioItems(id="display_figure",
                           options=[{'label': 'None', 'value': 'Nope'},
                                    {'label': 'Figure 1', 'value': 'Figure1'},
                                    {'label': 'Figure 2', 'value': 'Figure2'},
                                    {'label': 'Figure 3', 'value': 'Figure3'}
                                    ],
                           value='Nope',
                           labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block', 'width': '10em', 'line-height': '0.5em'}
                           )
        ],
    ),
        dcc.FormGroup(
            [dcc.Label(""), ]
        ),
    ],
    body=True,
    style={'font-size': 'large'})

app.layout = dcc.Container(
    [
        html.H1("Button for predictions"),
        html.Hr(),
        dcc.Row([
            dcc.Col([controls], xs=4),
            dcc.Col([
                dcc.Row([
                    dcc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="predictions")),
                ])
            ]),
        ]),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Row([

        ]),
    ],
    fluid=True,
)


@app.callback(
    Output("predictions", "figure"),
    [Input("display_figure", "value"),

     ],
)
def make_graph(display_figure):
    # main trace
    y = 'Prices'
    y2 = 'Predicted_prices'
    #     print(display_figure)
    if 'Nope' in display_figure:
        fig = go.Figure()
        fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)', paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                          yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, tickfont=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)')),
                          xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, tickfont=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)')))
        return fig

    if 'Figure1' in display_figure:
        fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(name=y, x=df.index, y=df[y], mode='lines'))
        fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(name=y, x=df.index, y=df[y2], mode='lines'))
        fig.update_layout(template='plotly_dark')

    # prediction trace
    if 'Figure2' in display_figure:
        fig = go.Figure((go.Scatter(name=y, x=df.index, y=df[y], mode='lines')))
        fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(name=y, x=df.index, y=df[y2], mode='lines'))
        fig.update_layout(template='seaborn')

    if 'Figure3' in display_figure:
        fig = go.Figure((go.Scatter(name=y, x=df.index, y=df[y], mode='lines')))
        fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(name=y, x=df.index, y=df[y2], mode='lines'))
        fig.update_layout(template='plotly_white')

    # Aesthetics
    fig.update_layout(margin={'t': 30, 'b': 0, 'r': 0, 'l': 0, 'pad': 0})
    fig.update_layout(hovermode='x')
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, legend=dict(x=1, y=0.85))
    fig.update_layout(uirevision='constant')
    fig.update_layout(title="Prices and predictions")

    return (fig)


app.run_server(debug=True)
```

but I got the following error and couldn't proceed further.

```
line 24, in <module>
    controls = dcc.Card(
AttributeError: module 'dash_core_components' has no attribute 'Card'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the different components used in your code are defined in different libraries (`dash_core_components`, `dash_html_components` and
`dash_bootstrap_components`), while you are trying to get all the components from the same library (`dash_core_components`). For instance, `dcc.Card` should be replaced with `dbc.Card` where `dbc` stands for `dash_bootstrap_components`, see the code below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Prices': [1, 10, 7, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Predicted_prices': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, 8, 6, 9]
})

# app setup
app = dash.Dash()

# controls
controls = dbc.Card([

        dbc.FormGroup([

            html.Label('Options'),

            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='display_figure',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'None', 'value': 'None'},
                    {'label': 'Figure 1', 'value': 'Figure1'},
                    {'label': 'Figure 2', 'value': 'Figure2'},
                    {'label': 'Figure 3', 'value': 'Figure3'}
                ],
                value='None',
                labelStyle={
                    'display': 'inline-block',
                    'width': '10em',
                    'line-height': '0.5em'
                }
            )

        ]),

    ],

    body=True,
    style={'font-size': 'large'}

)

app.layout = dbc.Container([

        html.H1('Button for predictions'),

        html.Hr(),

        dbc.Row([

            dbc.Col([controls], xs=4),

            dbc.Col([
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='predictions')),
                ])

            ]),
        ]),

    ],

    fluid=True,

)


@app.callback(
    Output('predictions', 'figure'),
    [Input('display_figure', 'value')],
)
def make_graph(display_figure):

    y = 'Prices'
    y2 = 'Predicted_prices'

    if 'Figure1' in display_figure:
        fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(name=y, x=df.index, y=df[y], mode='lines'))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name=y, x=df.index, y=df[y2], mode='lines'))
        fig.update_layout(template='plotly_dark')
        fig.update_layout(title='Prices and predictions')

    elif 'Figure2' in display_figure:
        fig = go.Figure((go.Scatter(name=y, x=df.index, y=df[y], mode='lines')))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name=y, x=df.index, y=df[y2], mode='lines'))
        fig.update_layout(template='seaborn')
        fig.update_layout(title='Prices and predictions')

    elif 'Figure3' in display_figure:
        fig = go.Figure((go.Scatter(name=y, x=df.index, y=df[y], mode='lines')))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(name=y, x=df.index, y=df[y2], mode='lines'))
        fig.update_layout(template='plotly_white')
        fig.update_layout(title='Prices and predictions')

    else:
        fig = go.Figure()
        fig.update_layout(
            plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, tickfont=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)')),
            xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, tickfont=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)'))
        )

    fig.update_layout(margin={'t': 30, 'b': 0, 'r': 0, 'l': 0, 'pad': 0})
    fig.update_layout(hovermode='x')
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, legend=dict(x=1, y=0.85))
    fig.update_layout(uirevision='constant')

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

Once you have fixed this issue, you can update the app to display the static PNG files instead of the interactive graphs as shown below. Note that the `dcc.Graph` component has been replaced by the `html.Img` component, and that the `figure` property has been replaced by the `src` property.

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

# app setup
app = dash.Dash()

# controls
controls = dbc.Card([

        dbc.FormGroup([

            html.Label('Options'),

            dcc.RadioItems(
                id='display_figure',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'None', 'value': 'None'},
                    {'label': 'Figure 1', 'value': 'Figure1'},
                    {'label': 'Figure 2', 'value': 'Figure2'},
                    {'label': 'Figure 3', 'value': 'Figure3'}
                ],
                value='None',
                labelStyle={
                    'display': 'inline-block',
                    'width': '10em',
                    'line-height': '0.5em'
                }
            )

        ]),

    ],

    body=True,
    style={'font-size': 'large'}

)

app.layout = dbc.Container([

        html.H1('Button for predictions'),

        html.Hr(),

        dbc.Row([

            dbc.Col([controls], xs=4),

            dbc.Col([
                dbc.Row([
                    dbc.Col(html.Img(id='predictions')),
                ])

            ]),
        ]),

    ],

    fluid=True,

)

@app.callback(
    Output('predictions', 'src'),
    [Input('display_figure', 'value')],
)
def make_graph(display_figure):

    if 'Figure1' in display_figure:
        return app.get_asset_url('image_1.png')

    elif 'Figure2' in display_figure:
        return app.get_asset_url('image_2.png')

    elif 'Figure3' in display_figure:
        return app.get_asset_url('image_3.png')

    else:
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True)
```

Note also that the PNG files will need to be saved in the `assets` folder, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. The above solution works. My use case is I have already generated 3 png files as image_1, image_2 and image_3. How do I render these static images when I click on buttons. The above example generates scatter plot but in my case I want to display these static images. Please let me know one example. Thanks again.

Comment: YES. It works and I could render static Images and I am sure this example will be useful for many. Thanks again.